# Alternate row color based on field value

Tags: php

Consider the following code:

```
<?php foreach($payment_type->revisionHistory as $history): ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?= $history->userResponsible()->alias ?></td>
        <td><?= $history->fieldName() ?></td>
        <td><?= $history->oldValue() ?></td>
        <td><?= $history->newValue() ?></td>
        <td><?= $history->created_at ?></td>
    </tr>                        
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I would like to be able to change row color ONLY when the `created_at` field value is different from the previous iteration, and maintain the same row color while the value is the same.

I have tried some ways, but the results were really miserable.

Comment: @zerkms Ternary would be so much better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should mix it with css, but it's quite easy:

```
<?php 
$lastCreatedAt = ''; // for storing value of the previous date, start with empty
$classNameEven = TRUE; // begin with "even" class
foreach($payment_type->revisionHistory as $history):

   $switchClass = ($lastCreatedAt != $history->created_at);
   if ($switchClass) {
      $classNameEven = !$classNameEven;
   }
?>
    <tr class="<?php echo ($classNameEven ? 'even' : 'odd'); ?>">
        <td><?= $history->userResponsible()->alias ?></td>
        <td><?= $history->fieldName() ?></td>
        <td><?= $history->oldValue() ?></td>
        <td><?= $history->newValue() ?></td>
        <td><?= $history->created_at ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php  //remember the last date for next iteration
    $lastCreatedAt = $history->created_at; 
    ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Then you need to add some CSS to this table, like this:

```
<style>
table tr.even td {
   background-color: #FFF;
}
table tr.odd td {
   background-color: #999; //odd rows have darker background
}
</style>
```

Comment: This is really nice, thank you. I never saw the construct `$classNameEven = !$classNameEven`, does it alternate a boolean value?

Comment: Yes, it negates it - changes it from `TRUE` to `FALSE` and the other way round, depending on the initial value.